# find the position of a specific number within a string

Tags: sql, hive

I am looking to find the position of first 7 that i see in a string of numbers (first 7 from left) 
suppose i have the following example

```
Id   pp
1    11157899
2    71166678
3    72345243
```

i want the output to look like this

```
Id   pp          pos
1    11157897    8
2    21166678    7
3    72375243    4
```

How can i do this in hive sql.

Comment: there is a little button in the text editor that looks like `{}`. Highlight your code (your tables in this question) and hit that button to have it format properly. Alternatively you can add 4 spaces to the beginning of each line of your table or code to have it format.

Comment: the expected output is different from the explanation.please mention wht you need more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

you can use locate function

> Returns the position of the first occurrence of substr in str after
>   position pos.

this is sample query

```
select locate('7', reverse(cast(7123 as string)));    -- 1
```

if there is no '7' present in your number, it will return 0